# C++ - Determine instance of foo in templated function pointer argument call

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I'm playing around with function-pointer calls and callbacks and trying to write a function which can take any function-pointer, log the function call and call the function-pointer after. Here is a code to show you what I'm trying to do:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<functional>

int foo4(std::function<int(int)> Fn, int&& val)
{
    return Fn(std::forward<int>(val));
}

template<typename Fn>
int foo5(Fn fn)
{
    return 10;
}

template <typename T, typename... args>
T(*LogAndCall(T(*ptr)(args...)))(args...)
{
    std::cout << "Logging function call to: " << ptr << " with " << sizeof...(args) << " argument(s)" << std::endl;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    //call func1
    auto r4 = LogAndCall(foo4)([](int&& x) {
        return x * 10;
    }, 100);
    std::cout << "Ret value: " << r4 << std::endl << std::endl;

    //call foo5
    auto r5 = LogAndCall(foo5<specialization?>)([](int x) { //<--- problem
        return x;
    });

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the problem is with calling foo5 with the following error:

Looks like I need to specify `foo5<something>` but the question is, what? :)

Comment: How can a compiler deduce which `foo5<U>` you want if `U` must match `args` which is a type template parameter as well?

Comment: Exactly, I know what the problem is. I just don't know how to specify what <U> is since its a function. Is there a way to tell the compiler its a function call like foo5<int> but foo5<magical function call>?

Comment: For a non-capturing lambda you can force a decay to a pointer `foo5<int(int)>`; if it's a capturing lambda you can say `foo5<std::function<int(int)>>`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki who knew, that worked mate cheers. Guess there is no way to specify anything for capturing lambdas except for std::function which gives a overhead right? Also you should provide that as an answer.

Comment: You can always store your lambda expression to a variable, and then say `foo5<decltype(lambda)>)(lambda)`

Comment: @CamelToe Hi, can you please tell me what kind of sorcery is `LogAndCall`? My brain can't parse that.

Comment: @LogicStuff haha its a variadic templated function returning a function pointer. The syntax looks weird but you can rewrite it with typedefs and make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Looks like I need to specify `foo5<something>` but the question is, what?*

For a non-capturing lambda you can force decay to a pointer:

```
auto r5 = LogAndCall(foo5<int(int)>)([](int x){
//                        ~~~~~~~^
    return x;
});
```

If it's a capturing lambda, you can use a type erasing technique:

```
auto r6 = LogAndCall(foo5<std::function<int(int)>>)([&](int x){
//                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    return x;
});
```

Alternatively, you can store your lambda to a variable so that you can query its type with the `decltype()` specifier:

```
auto lambda = [&](int x){
    return x;
};
auto r7 = LogAndCall(foo5<decltype(lambda)>)(lambda);
//                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0faa4d2b519edf80)

Comment: Give this guy some love :) Cheers Piotr that solved the problem mate.